# Weak sequential compactness in a reflexive space

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, normed-spaces

Let $\{X, \| \cdot \|\}$ be a normed space, $B$ is the unit ball of $X$. If $\{X, \| \cdot \|\}$ is reflexive, then is $B$ weakly sequentially compact?  If it's not true, are there any counterexamples for this?

Comment: Yes, and it follows from the [Banach-Alaoglu theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem#Consequences).

Comment: but for Banach-Alaoglu theorem, it should be Banach Space?  thank you~

Comment: @user142719 For any normed space, $X^*$ and $X^{**}$ are Banach spaces. And you assume reflexivity, so...

Comment: The Banach-Alaoglu Theorem says the unit ball is weakly-*compact*, not that it is weakly-*sequentially-compact*.  So some further argument is necessary if $X$ is not separable.  It seems to me that you could show that the convex closure of any sequence is metrizable with respect to the weak topology (using a metric similar to the one described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem#Sequential_Banach.E2.80.93Alaoglu_theorem).

Comment: If $X$ is reflexive, it's a Banach space and $B$ is weakly compact. Now see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberlein%E2%80%93%C5%A0mulian_theorem).

Comment: Thank you for all, I was too careless to find reflexive is banach